# SHOW COLUMN escaping mechanism

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I have a column called `\'column`. I am able to use it in SELECT statements just like any other column. However, when I try to perform `SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable LIKE '\\''column'` I get no results. I observed that it works if I double escape the backslash: `'\\\\''column'`.

I tested this from MariaDB console, but I also observed the same behaviour in MySQL 8.

How does the escaping work? How should I properly escape the value so that I can fetch the column information?

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cb7zjH7BDJafttVMR9eVaM/0)

Comment: It's interpreted twice, so one escape is for the like, one for MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

> MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, \n to represent
> the newline character). If you want a LIKE string to contain a literal
> , you must double it. (Unless the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` SQL mode is
> enabled, in which case no escape character is used.) For example, to
> search for `\n`, specify it as `\\n`. To search for `\`, specify it as `\\\\`;
> this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and
> again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be
> matched against.